# Is it possible to dump the yaml file in another directory on same system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

Here is my directory on raspberry pi:

```
Home
  |__pi 
      |__test1
      |__test2
          |__  abc.py
```

I am running a python code (`abc.py`) that edit and then dump a YAML file. But the file is saved in the same directory (i.e in test2). Is it possible to dump the YAML file in another directory (i.e in test1)?
If yes, then please let me know the code.

Here is my python code:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

inp = """\
# example
name:
  # details
  family: Smith   # very common
  given: Alice    # one of the siblings
"""

yaml = YAML()
code = yaml.load(inp)
code['name']['given'] = 'Bob'

yaml.dump(code, sys.stdout)
```

Comment: Your example is not dumping to code to a file, so it does't really match your description of what you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

The second parameter to the `.dump()` method can be a stream like `sys.stdout` or a stream that is an opened file:

```
with open('../code1/output.yaml', 'w') as fp:
    yaml.dump(code, fp)
```

As you are on Python3, you also have `pathlib` as part of the standard library and you can pass a `pathlib.Path` as second parameter to `.dump()`:

```
from pathlib import Path
output = Path('../code1/output.yaml')
yaml.dump(code, output)
```

The `Path` will be properly opened for writing and closed.

(You can also load from a `Path` by doing, `yaml.load(Path('some/path/to/a/file'))`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.